# Загрузка текста из Интернета

Tags: delphi

Есть сайт, на котором расположен файл `text.txt`.

Задача: загрузить его содержимое, например, в `Memo`.

Я хотел сделать так - скачивать этот файл и потом открывать его, но я думаю, есть способ полегче.

Comment: http://delphidevelop.ru/publ/35-1-0-217

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var 
sl:TstringList;
begin
sl:TstringList.create;
sl.text:=idHTTP1.Get('http:/BLABLABLA.COM/text.txt');
Memo1.text:=sl.Text;
sl.free;
end;
```

еще вариант без использования **TStringList**

```
begin
Memo1.text:=idHTTP1.Get('http:/BLABLABLA.COM/text.txt');
end;
```